# How to get an EXACT match from a string inside a file Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made myself a bot that would simply get an argument from Discord and if the argument had matched it would send the message "Successfully Redeemed." That part works BUT what doesnt work is the exact match. I Want it to exactly match in order for that message to come up but suppose a key is `123456` it would also accept an argument as `12` or `123`. I don't want that to happen, it should **EXACTLY** match. Here is my current code:

```
    if (command === '$redeemkey') {
        const fs = require('fs')
        fs.readFile('notredeemed.txt', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if(data.includes(`${args[0]}`)){
            console.log("true")
                 return message.reply({
                embeds: [
                    new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('GREEN')
                    .setDescription('Redeemed Successfully')
                ]
            })
            }
```

Here is what my `notredeemed.txt` looks like:

```
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
```

Comment: Is there a specific length of the codes?

Comment: No specific amount, I add the codes in the txt file by doing $gencode which creates a random code. So no no specific amount.

Comment: Use regex or the `==` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.includes()` would check for the argument in the entire file content no matter which position it is in.

---

### Solution #1

You could instead use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in order to [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the exact value based on the line content.

- `^` - Start of string
- `$` - End of string
- `m` - Multi-line

Replace:

```js
data.includes(`${args[0]}`)
```

With:

```js
data.toString().match(new RegExp(`^${args[0]}$`, "m"))
```

---

### Solution #2

You could [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) the line breaks in the data and then check if the created array contains the argument, similarly to how you tried checking for the value at first.

Replace:

```js
data.includes(`${args[0]}`)
```

With:

```js
data.toString().split("\n").includes(`${args[0]}`);
```

Comment: `data` is a Buffer, first, convert it to a string using the `toString()` method and then call the `match()` method.

Comment: It works! But it accepts all of them as a key (meaning it would accept even letters). @James

Comment: you can use `isNaN` like `data.toString().split("\n").includes(isNaN(\`${args[0]}\`));`

Comment: solution 1 worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the codes by line break and then test for their equality. The `some` method is used, to return early if a match is found.

```
fs.readFile('test.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let value = args[0];

    let codes = data.toString().split(/\r?\n/);

    let result = codes.some((code) => {
        if ( code === value ) return true;
    });

    console.log(result); // for visually check whether a match was found.
    return result;
});
```

contents of the file

```
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
```

Comment: seems to come us Refrence Error: "Result is undefined"

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: still seems to accept anything i do e.g 1 or 12

Comment: Check the updated answer. Also, can you show how args[0] gets its value?

Comment: the solution above worked the one i have corrected